# Expected KMM XCFramwork size (with Ktor)

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

So we started to use KMM with Ktor in production in our company and we noticed something strange. I just wanted to make sure if this is expected or if we are doing something wrong or if there are any optimisations we are missing:

So basically adding just the Ktor Darwin engine to the iOS KMM module without the Ktor library inside the common code (and even when adding the Ktor core library in the common code, it almost doesn't increase the framework size at all) and without any code using Ktor, the binary size of the exported XCFramework binary file increases by 2.7MB.

Now I know that XCode does slight optimisations afterwards to the framework file but even after those the KMM library just with the Darwin engine increases the size of our iOS application significantly, especially compared to the previous native Networking code of the app.

I was wondering if this is expected behaviour, if there are any further optimisations and if everybody is encountering this or if maybe something is configured wrong on our side in the build set.

I already tried most the optimisations I know of, like making everything internal and so on, but again: This size increase is just by adding a lib in the iOS module, even if there is no code included by me using this lib.

We have some domain specific size constraints to our apps (for e.g. supporting App Clips, ...) so we have to get that size down somehow, otherwise we would have to switch back to native networking code which would be really sad because KMM is awesome!

Comment: have you found any solution or workaround for this?